# To read specific path string from generation of curl result(SED/AWK/Grep)

Tags: curl, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to read specific path(**/opt/links/stances/2**) from where I pulled out result using curl command.

Curl command:-

```
curl -s http://localhost:8080/stances/1/Dirs
```

Result from above command:-

```
{"LocalWorkingDir":"/opt/links/stances/1","Workers":[{"WorkerInstanceID":2,"WorkerHostname":"yolo.automation.local","WorkerInstanceRunDir":"/opt/links/stances/2"}]}
```

command i am trying to read **/opt/links/stances/2** from generated output :-

```
curl -s http://localhost:8080/stances/1/Dirs |  sed 's|$1|" "|' | awk '{print $1}'
```

I am ending up with no result.
Please help me with command to read the path(**/opt/links/stances/2**). thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use jq?

Comment: @oguzismail not sure how to use it!!

Comment: Well it's easy. Something like `jq -r '.Workers[0].WorkerInstanceRunDir'` should do what you want.

Comment: @oguzismail  system is configured with customized repository. i cannot use jq as its package is not available in repo!

Comment: That's bad. Good luck then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `gnu grep` then you can use a PCRE regex like this:

```sh
curl -s http://localhost:8080/stances/1/Dirs | 
grep -oP '"WorkerInstanceRunDir":"\K[^"]+'

/opt/links/stances/2
```

**Details:**

- `"WorkerInstanceRunDir":"`: Match literal text `"WorkerInstanceRunDir":"`
- `\K`: Reset matched info
- `[^"]+`: Match 1+ non-`"` characters

If you don't have `gnu grep` installed then use this `sed`:

```sh
curl -s http://localhost:8080/stances/1/Dirs |
sed -E 's/.*"WorkerInstanceRunDir":"([^"]+).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since OP can't install jq, following could be tried with shown samples. But this could not be full fledge, this is completely as per shown samples only.

```
awk 'match($0,/"WorkerInstanceRunDir":"[^"]*"}/){print substr($0,RSTART+24,RLENGTH-26)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `match` function to match regex `"WorkerInstanceRunDir":"[^"]*"}`, which will match everything from "WorkerInstanceRunDir till next occurrence of `"` followed by `}` then printing sub string starting from `RSTART+24` till value of `RLENGTH-26` here.

OR try setting field separators as per shown samples only.

```
awk -F'"|}' '$(NF-5)=="WorkerInstanceRunDir"{print $(NF-3)}' Input_file
```

Comment: By using `}` at the end of `match` regex, isn't it assuming that `WorkerInstanceRunDir` is last field in JSON output?

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you sir, I have changed the codes now to check about WorkerInstanceRunDir.